# knockout - button click is not working

Tags: knockout.js

Button click is not firing. Appreciate any help. 
Here is the jsfiddle link. https://jsfiddle.net/264aosnk/.
Code goes like this:

```
<body>
  <div id="topNavConstant" >
      <input placeholder="Enter search criteria" id="searchbox" data-     bind="value:criteria, valueUpdate:'afterkeydown'" type="search" autocomplete='off'/>
      <input type="button" value="Click" data-bind="click:searchresults"/>
  </div>
```

//script

```
function myModel(){
var self = this;
self.criteria = ko.observable("");

self.searchresults = ko.observable(function (){
    alert('Feature yet to come...'); 
});
}
ko.applyBindings(new myModel());
```

I dont see the alert message on clicking the button.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `click` binding in `knockout` uses an event `handler` which that means it is going to invoke a javascript function not an observable.https://jsfiddle.net/kyr6w2x3/27/

Change your click function to this

```
self.searchresults = function (){
    alert('Feature yet to come...'); 
};
```